# Are there any consequences of the initial object in Set being unique, while the isomorphism class of terminal objects is nontrivial?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Is this even a meaningful distinction?

Is there a more appropriate term than "isomorphism class"?

Is there something different about a theory of sets with a nontrivial set-isomorphism class of empty sets?

Comment: this is kind of an "evil" distinction; i.e. any theorem that can be stated inside category theory about the category of sets will not be able to see this.

Comment: That's a question that crossed my mind, but I don't think it has any mathematical content. You could modify the category of sets to an equivalent one with many isomorphic copies of the empty set and nothing substantial would change. A similar observation that could potentially have more content is that e.g. in the category of spaces every object weakly equivalent to the empty space is actually isomorphic to the empty space. In general strictifying weak equivalences to isomorphisms is a difficult thing, but here it seems far too trivial to be of any consequence.

Comment: While I'm inclined to agree with the previous comments, I do admit to having occasionally  pondered the fact that the standard material set theories deliver a unique initial object but a proper class of terminal objects.

Comment: That's just the axiom of extensionality, though. One also observes that the opposite of the category of complete atomic boolean algebras is equivalent to $\mathbf{Set}$ but has a proper class of initial (and terminal) objects.

Comment: This is a reasonable question, but I think the answer is just "no".

Comment: Perhaps a more meaningful question would be: Is there a *natural* category satisfying the ETCS axioms in which (a) the initial object is not unique, (b) the terminal object is unique. Of course it is very easy to construct examples, but most of them seem to be artificial. Zhen has suggested to look at the dual of the category of atomic boolean algebras. But I'm not sure if this is a ETCS category "on the nose", without using the equivalence to the category of sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distinction is meaningful in many senses.  Certainly it is on ZF foundations, and contrary to what Dylan Wilson might seem to suggest, the distinction can be stated formally in the Elementary Theory of the Category of Sets as well as in the standard axioms for the Category of Categories as Foundation.

I do not see any reason to use any term other than "isomorphism class."  That is a vague question.

As to the third question, there is no important difference.  You know you could require just one terminal set.  In ETCS or CCAF you could add a skeletal axiom saying there is just one set in each isomorphism class.  And on ZF foundations even without changing the definition of function you could pick one singleton and insist it is the only singleton allowed in your category.  It would not achieve anything important -- as you can sort of see from the triviality yet artificiality of the ZF way of doing it.